# How to make that elegant and succinct: "Live for the moments that make life worth living"

Tags: phrase-requests

My friend wants to get a tattoo in English. He's very specific about what he wants it to express, but for both of us English is a foreign language and we're not quite sure how to say that using a short but aesthetic phrase. The closest I can get as far as the meaning is concerned is this:

> Live for the moments that make life worth living

but that's too long and I guess not very elegant. Is there a good succinct way to express something like that in English?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions.

Comment: *carpe diem*...

Comment: @Drew   Nunc est bibendum.  Cheers!

Comment: Sounds like a marketing slogan for some brand of beer.

Answer (score 2):

"**Seize the day**".

Drew commented with "[Carpe Diem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpe_diem)" which seems apt, but if you want English not Latin use the English translation. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seize_the_Day), the English version is an expression in its own right nowadays, and is used for various bands, songs, films and even [tattoos](http://google.co.uk/search?q=tattoo%20%22seize%20the%20day%22)!

> **Seize the day** is the translation of the Latin saying Carpe diem.

Answer (score 1):

***Live life!*** (Also, check the synonyms below.)

ODO:

> **[live](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/live)**
> *VERB*
>
> **1.7** Have an exciting or fulfilling life: he couldn’t wait to get out of school and really start living
>
> Maybe you should start living instead of just watching everyone else.
>
> The voice is calling us to leave our foolish fears behind, to take
> risks, to trust, to begin to really live.
>
> Get out there and start living, you never know how much longer it is
> all going to last.
>
> **Synonyms**: enjoy oneself, **enjoy life**, have fun, be happy, **live life** to the full; flourish, prosper, thrive, make the most of life